# python - error py2exe (DLL missing)

Tags: python, numpy, dll, py2exe

I have tried to compile my python script to exe file with py2exe (python 2.7.14), but unfortunately i got this error while runnig this code:
(runs perfect in PyCharm)

```
 from distutils.core import setup
 import py2exe
 setup(console=['Dev.py'])

error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'numpy-atlas.dll'

so i tried  to fix it with this code:

from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe    
import numpy
import os
import sys      
def numpy_dll_paths_fix():
    paths = set()
    np_path = numpy.__path__[0]
    for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk(np_path):
        for item in filenames:
            if item.endswith('.dll'):
                paths.add(dirpath)
    sys.path.append(*list(paths))
numpy_dll_paths_fix()
setup(console=['dev.py'])
```

and now when i run it, i got this error:

Your executable(s) also depend on these dlls which are not included,
you may or may not need to distribute them.
Make sure you have the license if you distribute any of them, and
make sure you don't distribute files belonging to the operating system.

OLEAUT32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
USER32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
IMM32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.dll
COMCTL32.dll - C:\Python27\DLLs\COMCTL32.dll
WINMM.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINMM.dll
USER32.dll - C:\Python27\DLLs\USER32.dll
WS2_32.dll - C:\Python27\DLLs\WS2_32.dll
ADVAPI32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
mfc90.dll - C:\Users\Papom\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\Pythonwin\mfc90.dll
SHELL32.dll - C:\Python27\DLLs\SHELL32.dll
msvcrt.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
WS2_32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
GDI32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
COMDLG32.dll - C:\Python27\DLLs\COMDLG32.dll
GDI32.dll - C:\Python27\DLLs\GDI32.dll
ole32.dll - C:\Python27\DLLs\ole32.dll
NETAPI32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\NETAPI32.dll
IMM32.dll - C:\Python27\DLLs\IMM32.dll
KERNEL32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNEL32.dll
OLEAUT32.dll - C:\Python27\DLLs\OLEAUT32.dll
MSVCP90.dll - C:\Python27\MSVCP90.dll
KERNEL32.dll - C:\Python27\DLLs\KERNEL32.dll
ADVAPI32.dll - C:\Python27\DLLs\ADVAPI32.dll
VERSION.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\VERSION.dll
ole32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll
SHELL32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll
COMDLG32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\C OMDLG32.dll
WINSPOOL.DRV - C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV

when i try to run it igot this error:

```
C:\final\dist>dev.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "dev.py", line 9, in <module>
File "openpyxl\__init__.pyc", line 26, in <module>
File "openpyxl\compat\__init__.pyc", line 5, in <module>
File "openpyxl\compat\strings.pyc", line 9, in <module>
File "openpyxl\compat\numbers.pyc", line 28, in <module>
RuntimeError: Could not find the matplotlib data files
```

can someone help me to fix it please?

Comment: Are you sure it is an error? Looks like defauld py2exe output. Maybe you don't need these DLLs.